# What function f(x,m) will give me graphs that look like this? "Sigmoid-like" when x < m, linear when x >= m

Tags: graphing-functions

Is there an equation/function that will give me a graph that looks like the following? f is a function of x and m, where m is a "cutoff" variable--values of x less than m follow a "sigmoid-like" curve, and values of x greater than or less than m follow a linear path. The curve as x nears m must also be smooth--no hard edges. Lastly, when x = 0, y = 0. When x = 1, y = 1.

Here is a picture of what I'm after:

[image]

Comment: I think you can build one out of the usual [Logisitc Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function).  Just match value and first derivative at the point you want to linearize the function.

Comment: @lulu yea that looks like the right way to go. i'll try that out and post an answer